# App is taking really long time to load first activity

Tags: android

My app is taaking a really long time ~20 seconds on Nexus 6 before calling `onCreate` method of launcher activity of my app. 
These are logs before my first activity becomes visible.

```
04-12 19:30:46.564 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp-1/lib/arm
04-12 19:31:05.862 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp-1/lib/arm
04-12 19:31:05.909 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
04-12 19:31:05.909 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/MultiDex: install
04-12 19:31:05.910 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
04-12 19:31:06.045 12518-13453/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162190): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/sysrq-trigger" dev="proc" ino=4026544381 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_sysrq:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162191): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/1" dev="proc" ino=8630890 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162192): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/2" dev="proc" ino=8630891 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162193): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/3" dev="proc" ino=8630892 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162194): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/7" dev="proc" ino=8630893 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162195): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/8" dev="proc" ino=8630894 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162196): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/9" dev="proc" ino=8630895 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162197): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/10" dev="proc" ino=8630896 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162198): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/11" dev="proc" ino=8630897 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162199): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/12" dev="proc" ino=8630898 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162200): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/15" dev="proc" ino=8630899 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.174 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162201): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/16" dev="proc" ino=8630900 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162202): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/19" dev="proc" ino=8630901 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162203): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/20" dev="proc" ino=8630902 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162204): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/23" dev="proc" ino=8630903 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162205): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/24" dev="proc" ino=8630904 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162206): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/26" dev="proc" ino=8630905 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162207): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/28" dev="proc" ino=8630906 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162208): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/29" dev="proc" ino=8630907 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:06.184 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/sh.dealsmashapp: type=1400 audit(0.0:162209): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/30" dev="proc" ino=8630908 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
04-12 19:31:08.740 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.8.97
04-12 19:31:08.772 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/LoginManager: initInstance
04-12 19:31:08.817 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/ContentManager: initInstance
04-12 19:31:08.825 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/BeaconManager: initInstance
04-12 19:31:08.907 12518-13554/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-12 19:31:09.086 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/LoginActivity: onCreate
04-12 19:31:09.585 12518-12524/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.012ms
04-12 19:31:09.727 12518-12518/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp D/ContentManager: fetching all interests
04-12 19:31:09.904 12518-13554/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 52af4d2, I8366cd0437
                                                                Build Date                       : 10/20/15
                                                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                                                                Local Branch                     : M14
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Reconstruct Branch               : 
04-12 19:31:09.909 12518-13554/com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Please note that app started at 46th second but the `onCreate` method of my first activity `LoginActivity` is called on 9th second of the next minute.
First, I suspected that it is due to some newly added dependency but the issue is still their after i removed them. Here is my Module's `build.gradle` file just in case.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        releaseConfig {
            keyAlias 'ds_a'
            keyPassword 'dealsmash'
            storeFile file('C:/Android/keystore/dealsmash_android.keystore')
            storePassword 'dealsmash'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dealsmash.dealsmashapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 21
        versionName "2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
//    maven { url 'https://github.com/taplytics/Taplytics-Android-SDK/raw/master/AndroidStudio/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.2.4'
    compile 'com.kontaktio.sdk:kontakt-sdk:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:design:${android_support_lib_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${android_support_lib_version}"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') { transitive = true; }
    //    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:1.3'
    compile 'com.bugfender.sdk:android:0.1.8-SNAPSHOT'

    //  compile 'com.github.nitinverma:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.2.0:release@aar'

    // Taplytics
    //    compile("com.taplytics.sdk:taplytics:+@aar")
    // Dependencies for Taplytics
    //    compile("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:+")
    //    compile("com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:+")
    //Excluding org.json due to compiler warnings
    //    compile("com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:+") {
    //        exclude group: "org.json"
    //    }
    //    compile("com.github.nkzawa:engine.io-client:+") {
    //        exclude group: "org.json"
    //    }
}
```

Here is my `Application` class.

```
public class DealSmashApplication extends Application
{
    private Tracker mTracker;
    public PollManager pollManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Bugfender.init(this, "Eu6Djgg8dakcYwjBQKIlmYL9A3Xxo7AK", BuildConfig.DEBUG);
//        Taplytics.startTaplytics(this, "ce36925556402e12404b38586de9cb5fb7d4e5ec");
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        LoginManager.initInstance(this);
        pollManager = PollManager.initInstance(this);
        ContentManager.initInstance(this);
        BeaconManager.initInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate()
    {
        AlertsAndLogs.log("Application", "onTerminate");
        super.onTerminate();
        pollManager.stopPolling();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the default {@link Tracker} for this {@link Application}.
     *
     * @return tracker
     */
    synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker()
    {
        if (mTracker == null)
        {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing lots of initialization in onCreate(), measure how much each initInstance() method takes and draw conclusions from there.

Comment: Using Instant Run on Android Studio 2.0? It has such problems.

Comment: @laalto yes I am doing  that. But the problem doesnt just occurs when installing from Android studio. When I clear data of the app and then start it, it again takes that much time to load up.

Comment: how much dex files you have?

Answer (score 1):

To find out which method takes long you can try to use this 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Do you really need all that methods in the application on create? I supspect one of them is take a while

Comment: The problem is BEFORE onCreate().